# A way to use same script for multiple spreadsheets?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I currently have a script I am using in the script editor for over 20 spreadsheets. Every time I make a change to one, I have to make a change to the other 19. Is there a way to use one script and reference the rest so that any change I make I only have to do it to one?

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  Use a Library.  In your code editor, choose the FILE menu item, and PROPERTIES.  A dialog box will pop up.  Copy out the project key.  Now go to RESOURCES, LIBRARIES, and a dialog box will pop up.  In sheets that will not have the original code, enter the project key of the Apps Script, that has the main code.

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guide_libraries

Keep in mind that there is nothing special you need to do to create a "Library".  All a Library is, is code that you've already created.  You are just using the Project Key.

Comment: awesome. Thank you. So for sheets that do not have the code do i have to set up the triggers again? I have onedit triggers set for the original script.

Comment: Good question.  I'm not sure.  You might need to experiment.